# how to make my service worker in a SSR REACT app cache html page sent by the server

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to add a service worker to my server side rendered react application, up till now I'm able to cache my bundle but not my css with the help of the `SWPrecacheWebpack` plugin but I can't make an offline response.

This is how I'm serving my html from the server :

```
if(comp != undefined){ 
const context = {}, store = createStore(reducers), { dispatch } = store, mobileDetect = mobileParser(req)
  dispatch(setMobileDetect(mobileDetect))
  const html = ReactDOM.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router context={context} location={req.path}>
            <App context={context} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>)
  const preloadedState = store.getState()
  res.send(renderApp(html,preloadedState))
}else{
  res.end()
} 
} catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
        res.status(400).send(renderApp('An error occured.'));
  }
```

Can anyone please help me out? My css is served from a public directory not the same as my js.